# Can different versions of Windows Server Domain Controllers co-exist peacefully?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am being asked to turnup a windows 2003 R2 domain controller in a Windows 2008 R2 forest.
The company is too cheap to get another license for 2008 r2 and wants a second DC.

The functional level of the current domain / forest is windows 2003. What issues if any will I run in to?

Comment: What does "turnup a..." even mean? It's not a technical term I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing your terminology (and in turn, me!). You say you have a Windows 2008 R2 forest and then go on to say your domain/forest is Windows 2003. Please could you clarify what your domain and forest functional level *really* are.

If your domain and forest functional levels really are 2003, you'll have no issues. We've been running with 1 2008 R2 and 1 2003 Domain Controller for some time with no issue.

---

If however your domain/forest level is 2008, basically you're out of luck.

You should give this [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787290%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) a read on Active Directory functional levels. I'll call out the relevant bit for you (emphasis mine).

> - After the domain functional level is
>     raised, domain controllers running
>     earlier versions of Windows Server
>     cannot be introduced into the domain.
>     **After the forest functional level is
>     raised, domain controllers running
>     earlier versions of Windows Server
>     cannot be introduced into the forest.**